# DataGridView deleting

Tags: vb.net

My problem is when I use DataGridView I try to delete some of the rows. i do than i check if they are deleted in the preview. When i check the rows are still there. Trying to delete rows so when someadds a row they dont see all 100 rows that show up. Code:

```
Private Sub btnClear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click

     For Each row As DataRow In Me.Game_timeDataSet4._User_scores.Rows

     row.Delete()

     Next
Me.User_scoresTableAdapter.Update(Game_timeDataSet4._User_scores)

End Sub
```

Comment: You can't modify the collection in a For Each.

Comment: @LarsTech, that's not what's happening here because `Delete` does not modify the collection.  It simply flags the row as `Deleted` but the row remains in the `Rows` collection of its `DataTable`.

Comment: @FrankLogo, what value is returned by that call to `Update`?

Comment: A better way to do this would be to use a `For` loop, with an integer going from **0**, then loop through `Me.Game_timeDataSet4._User_scores.Rows.Count`. You can then do what you want with `Me.Game_timeDataSet4_User_scores.Rows(your_variable_here)`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I get an `InvalidOperationException was unhandled, Collection was modified; enumeration operation might not execute.` when I run code like this.

Comment: @LarsTech, I don't, or at least I don't when using an untyped `DataTable`. I haven't tested with a typed `DataTable` but I can't see any reason that it would be any different, given that that code treats it like an it's untyped anyway. Are you sure that you didn't call `Remove` rather than `Delete`?

Comment: @FrankLogo, is an exception being thrown when you execute that code?  If so then give us the error message, as you should have in the first place.  If not, how EXACTLY are you checking whether the rows have been deleted?

Comment: I get no error message. To check to see if there are deleted I go to the preview in the DataGridView i click the little arrow then I go to preview data. When I click the preview button it shows me all the rows that are still in the table.